# IBM Websphere 8.5 not adding web container custom properties to System

Tags: java, websphere

according to the IBM WAS documentation I have read, any custom properties added to the web container will appear in the Java *System.getProperties()* collection.

So, on my local DEV environment, I configure these properties in the WAS console via:

```
Application servers-->(servername)-->Web container-->Custom properties
```

However, on a customer's environment, these custom properties are *not* appearing in the Java *System.getProperties()* collection. The customer had to add them directly to the JVM properties.

The reason we need these properties is because we've written a global servlet context listener (e.g. configured via the listeners= parameter in the web container) and its the only mechanism available to give a global *listener* any configuration parameters.

Is there some obscure WAS 8.5 setting which governs this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it is working as designed.  To set a property accessible via **System.getProperties()** you would configure via [**JVM Custom Properties**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/xrun_jvm.html).  This is a separate set of properties than the [**Web Container custom properties**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html).

Comment: Yes you are right, I eventually realized the difference between web container properties and JVM properties. Do you know if there is a way to make our context listener read the web container properties?

Comment: Not sure if there is such a way.  Did you really want/need to read one of those web container properties or were you just hoping it was a convenient place to capture just the properties intended for your listener (without getting them mixed up with others)?   If the latter, you might have to just use a naming convention.

Comment: Its because I use the webshere mechanism to deploy a global servlet context listener that fires for every app deployed within a container. Having it look for configuration properties at the JVM level means there's no way to provide separate configurations if I have two containers running